# undefined symbol trying to run Sanic application in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.5, undefined-symbol, gentoo, sanic

When I try to run a Sanic application with Python 3.5, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sanic import Sanic
  File "/home/shiro/dev/unassociated/user-api/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sanic/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sanic.app import Sanic
  File "/home/shiro/dev/unassociated/user-api/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sanic/app.py", line 14, in <module>
    from sanic.handlers import ErrorHandler
  File "/home/shiro/dev/unassociated/user-api/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sanic/handlers.py", line 14, in <module>
    from sanic.response import text, html
  File "/home/shiro/dev/unassociated/user-api/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sanic/response.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ujson import dumps as json_dumps
ImportError: /home/shiro/dev/unassociated/user-api/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ujson.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: Buffer_AppendShortHexUnchecked
```

It runs in a virtual environment created with the command `virtualenv -ppython3.5 .venv --no-site-packages`

I'm on gentoo but I recompiled all related packages, and I don't know how to tackle this issue. Can anyone help?

Comment: For future lookups: here is link to github issues [ujson won't import on FreeBSD](https://github.com/esnme/ultrajson/issues/180)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a hack, and it isn't pretty, but this is how I resolved my issue while install Matrix's Synapse server (RIOT chat). Within the virtualenv it pulls down a precompiled shared object from pip. So I installed ujson from portage and copied the shared object in the virtaulenv.

I hope this helps you.